# Using conditions to match multiple patterns within a line

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a fasta file like this:
`myfasta.fasta`

```
>1_CDS
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAATTATTA
>2_CDS
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>3_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>4_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>5_rRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>6_tRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
```

I have a code that I want to use to separate sequences based on their ids that have matching patterns like 'CDS', 'tRNA' etc.  In the code below, I am trying to use startswith and also match pattern in line which doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me how to look for two conditions in line in python.

code: `python mycode.py myfasta.fasta`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
myfasta = sys.argv[1]
fasta = open(myfasta)

for line in fasta:
    if line.startswith('>') and 'CDS' in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print(line)
```

Expected output (if I use `CDS`):

```
>1_CDS
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAATTATTA
>2_CDS
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>3_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>4_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Mmmhh, seems like you're printing `line` anyway... How do you differentiate between positives and negatives?

Comment: seems like it works correctly. change the second print to something meaningful that could differentiate between having CDS and not having that.

Comment: yeah...code seems to do what you think, except that you're going to get blank lines because you have EOL at the end of each of your lines, and then print() is adding another one.

Comment: You're still just printing every line unconditionally!!!  You have to do something different depending on if your test succeeds or fails, or what's the point?

Comment: I do see the logic problem you're going to have.  You're going to need to keep track of if you've just matched a '>' line or not to decide if you should print a line without a '>'.  That's going to take a little thought, and probably a state variable.

Comment: You have to treat lines with '>' at the front differently than those without, regardless of if they match 'CDS' or not.  When you see '>' at the front of the line, you need to check to see if 'CDS' is in it to know if you should print it.  But you ALSO have to set a flag, so that the next time you see a line without a '>' at the front, you'll know if you should print that line or not.  That's the secret hear.  Create a boolean variable to keep track of if you printed the last '>' line you saw or not, and then use that variable to decide what to do with non-'>' lines

Comment: You misunderstand me.  I'm telling you what you have to do to get the output you want - you have to be able to print some of your lines even if they don't match your test, because you want to print or not print lines without '>' at the front, based on the prior line.

Comment: do you see what I'm getting at?  If so, how about trying to add some .more logic and show us what you've tried next.  HINT: take ` and 'CDS' in line` off of your `if` line.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you. You want to always process the '>' lines in one code block, even if you won't always print them.  You then have to decide in that block if you should print the line or not, and here's the key...you need to REMEMBER if you printed the line or not.   Then, you do want your 'else:' block, but that block should use the fact that you remembered what you did on the prior line to decide if that line (a line without a '>') should be printed.

Comment: No problem.  This is how you learn!

Comment: easiest with Biopython: `from Bio import SeqIO; SeqIO.write((r for r in SeqIO.parse('in.fa', 'fasta') if 'CDS' in r.id), 'out.fa', 'fasta')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code that works for you. If a line has CDS, it prints the line and the next lines. `strip()` removes the endline character while printing the line.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
myfasta = sys.argv[1]

flag = False
with open(myfasta) as fasta:
    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith('>') and 'CDS' in line:
            flag = True
        elif line.startswith('>'):
            flag = False
        if flag:
            print(line.strip())
```

**Edit**: You can remove the elif part as the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
myfasta = sys.argv[1]

flag = False
with open(myfasta) as fasta:
    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            flag = 'CDS' in line
        if flag:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Ok i changed the code. the first one was based on your current inputs

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting multiple lines with your inputs.

Comment: You should probably close the file at the end, or use a `with` context manager.

Comment: `if line.startswith('>'): flag = 'CDS' in line`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Do you mean that I should change flag from boolean type to a more general type?

Comment: i mean exactly what i wrote, `flag` is still a boolean, but you can remove your `elif` clause

Comment: Yeah. I didn't understand you first. My solution was just a quick one. But as it's marked as the answer I should make it as more efficient as possible. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Maanijou's answer is fine.

Also, consider an alternative with a iterator instead.

#### EDIT: Updated the code based on your comments

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
myfasta = sys.argv[1]
fasta = open(myfasta, "r+")

file_contents = iter(fasta)

try:
    print_flag = True
    while True:
        line = file_contents.next()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if "CDS" in line:
                print (line.strip())
                print_flag = True
            else:
                print_flag = False
        else:
            if print_flag:
                print (line.strip())

except StopIteration:
    print ("Done")
    fasta.close()
```

#### Explanation

`file_contents = iter(fasta)` converts the iterable file object into an iterator on which you can simply keep calling `next()` till you run out of things to read

Why I do not recommend calling `readlines` as some other answers have is that sometimes fasta files can be big and calling `readlines` consumes significant memory.

if a line satisfies your search req you simply print it and the next line, if not you simply read the next line and do nothing,

#### Explanation for Update

1. You got the Attribute error because of file modes, I could not reproduce it locally but I think opening the file with the right mode should fix it
2. You now said there could be more than 1 genome sequence for `CDS` updated the code to print all the genome sequences for 1 `CDS` header in the file

I tested it with a modified fasta file like so

```
>1_CDS
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGCG
>2_CDS
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>3_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>4_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>5_rRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>6_tRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
```

And this output

```
python fasta.py fasta.fasta
>1_CDS
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGCG
>2_CDS
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>3_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>4_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
Done
```

Comment: getting this error: `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: I think the error was because of file modes, I could not reproduce it locally, but I have added a fix which I think will fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
from collections import defaultdict

myfasta = sys.argv[1]
with open(myfasta) as fasta:
    data = fasta.read().splitlines()

pattern_data = defaultdict(list)
index = 0
while index < len(data):
    if data[index].startswith('>'):
        start = data[index].index('_') + 1
        key = data[index][start:]
        pattern_data[key].append(data[index + 1])
    index += 2
```

At this point you are free to do whatever you please with the sorted data.

The above assumes that the whole file you parse follows the exact format shown above: 1 line starting with a ">" that id's the single line that follows. If you have multiple lines that follow, the code needs minor modification.

EDIT:
I just read up on fasta files. I now know that they actually may have sequences that are longer than one line after they are identified. So the above code does need to be modified to account for multiline sequences. A more generalized approach is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
from collections import defaultdict

myfasta = sys.argv[1]
with open(myfasta) as fasta:
    data = fasta.read().splitlines()

id_line_indices = [index for index, line in enumerate(data) if line.startswith('>')]
id_line_indices.append(len(data))
pattern_buckets = defaultdict(list)

i = 0
while i < len(id_line_indices) - 1:
    start = data[id_line_indices[i]].index('_') + 1
    key = data[id_line_indices[i]][start:]

    sequence = [data[index] for index in range(id_line_indices[i] + 1, id_line_indices[i + 1])]
    sequence = ''.join(sequence)

    pattern_buckets[key].append(sequence)
    i += 1
```

This still achieves the same results for the above data set. For example,

```
print(pattern_buckets['CDS'])
print(pattern_buckets['rRNA'])
```

Will get you:

```
['AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGGG', 'TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA', 'TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT', 'TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT']
['TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA']
```